# Custom Api function not working during Postman testing

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Working on API's so I created a custom function to create and delete a ratings, when running tests on postman to check it's functionality does not seem to work

`ERROR MESSAGE: User matching query does not exist`

could this be an error on my code or I am not using postman properly?

Below is the code of the function

```
 @action(detail=True, methods=['POST'])
 def rate_movie(self, request, pk=None):

    if 'stars' in request.data:

        movie = Movie.objects.get(id=pk)
        user = User.objects.get(id=1)
        stars = request.data['stars']

        try:
            rating = Rating.objects.get(user=user.id, movie=movie.id)
            rating.stars = stars
            rating.save()
            serializer = RatingSerializer
            response = {'message': 'Rating Updated', 'results': serializer.data}
            return Response(response, status=HTTP_200_OK)

        except:
            rating = Rating.objects.create(user=user, movie=movie, stars=stars)
            serializer = RatingSerializer
            response = {'message': 'Rating Created', 'results': serializer.data}
            return Response(response, status=HTTP_200_OK)

    else:
        response = {'message':'Stars not selected for rating'}
        return Response(response, status=HTTP_400_bad_request)
```

Here is also a picture of sample request that I was trying when I wanted to test my function and also the error at which I am getting.

[image]

Comment: Error traceback says you don't have a **`User`** object with `PK=1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Arakkal Abu said, you're trying to do `User.objects.get(id=1)` but there's no `User` with `id=1`

Also, you might want to change
`Rating.objects.get(user=user.id, movie=movie.id)`
to
`Rating.objects.get(**user_id**=user.id, **movie_id**=movie.id)`